# can not sign-in via Twitter on UIWebView in Meteor

Tags: ios7, meteor

I am using accounts-twitter package in my meteor app.
It worked fine on desktop browsers, but you cannot sign-in on in-app UIWebView on iOS. Twitter calls back the app's callback URL, but no redirection to the app occurred since window.close() doesn't work on UIWebView.
Any idea to fix it?